# Is System.arraycopy an efficient way for memory shifting and heap usage?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

What I want to do is to shift a large array of bytes to 10 higher indexes. I know I can easily do it this way:

```
byte [] bArray = new byte [1000000];
System.arraycopy(bArray, 0 , bArray, 10, 900000 );
```

however, in our specific code we will be doing that every time we call a method, and that method is gonna be called a million times in our code. That makes us worry **about memory leak** as that is going go put lots of work on JVM to reallocate the **heap** over and over again in high frequency.

Comment: I would suggest redesigning your method. Any solution that doesn't invoke copying is faster than any solution on that does. Can you find a way of keeping track of what offset and length you are currently at in the array?

Comment: Or you might be able to use a list or array of length-10 arrays.  Definitely do *not* use your repeated calls to `arraycopy`, as this will kill your performance and will probably also corrupt your array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System.arraycopy is perfectly safe to use -- it will not cause "leaks" or somehow corrupt the array.  It's also the most efficient way to move large amounts of data within Java.

And System.arraycopy has nothing at all to do with heap management -- it doesn't allocate any additional storage.

That said, moving large amounts of data is not particularly efficient -- it "dirties" the caches, causing performance to crawl.  It's worthwhile to consider a different design.